# escaped html tags result from "for xml" clause

Tags: xml, t-sql, tags, escaping

I am extracting XML from a table using `FOR XML` clause.

```
select
    maincode as cod_deal
    , catcode as cod_category
    , catname as title_category
        ...
from myTable
for xml raw, elements
```

Some fields contains HTML tags (`<span>`s). The resulting XML display escaped tags:

```
&lt;span&gt;my field content&lt;/span&gt;
```

instead of

```
<span>my field content</span>
```

How may I prevent tsql escapes tags?

EDITED.
Note. Wrapping the `<![CDATA[...]]>` tag around the `<span>` tag does not do the work. The '<' and '>' characters of CDATA are escaped as well!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How may I prevent tsql escapes tags?

I'm not entirely sure that is what you want. But...

Sample data:

```
declare @T table
(
  Col varchar(50)
)

insert into @T values ('<span>my field content 1</span>')
insert into @T values ('<span>my field content 2</span>')
```

The equivalent of your query against this table:

```
select Col
from @T
for xml raw, elements, type
```

The result from this will be one row and one column that holds a XML document that looks like this:

```
<row>
  <Col>&lt;span&gt;my field content 1&lt;/span&gt;</Col>
</row>
<row>
  <Col>&lt;span&gt;my field content 2&lt;/span&gt;</Col>
</row>
```

This is the way it **has** to look if you want `<span>my field content 1</span>` to be the **value** of element `col`.

What you are asking for could be created like this:

```
select cast(Col as xml) as Col
from @T
for xml raw, elements, type
```

And this will also return one row with one XML column like this:

```
<row>
  <Col>
    <span>my field content 1</span>
  </Col>
</row>
<row>
  <Col>
    <span>my field content 2</span>
  </Col>
</row>
```

Here you have `<span>my field content 1</span>` as a **child node** to `Col` not as a value.

If you have your XML escaped you will get the correct values back when you extract them from the XML. Something like this in TSQL but **should** be the same in other languages.

```
declare @X xml
set @X = 
'<row>
  <Col>&lt;span&gt;my field content 1&lt;/span&gt;</Col>
</row>
<row>
  <Col>&lt;span&gt;my field content 2&lt;/span&gt;</Col>
</row>'

select T.N.value('Col[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Col
from @X.nodes('/row') as T(N)
```

Result:

```
Col
--------------------------------------------------
<span>my field content 1</span>
<span>my field content 2</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way is to put the encoded HTML tags back after you have the completed XML:

```
SELECT  REPLACE(REPLACE(( SELECT    maincode AS cod_deal ,
                                    catcode AS cod_category ,
                                    catname AS title_category
                          FROM      myTable
                        FOR
                          XML RAW ,
                              ELEMENTS
                        ), '&lt;', '<'), '&gt;', '>')
```

It's not pretty but it does the job - I use this approach a lot when using `FOR XML` to generate HTML tables in tsql & the cells of those tables need to preserve HTML tags such as spans etc.